# error_reporting(E_ALL) problem

Tags: php

i have put error_reporting(E_ALL) on top of my php page now i comment this but it gives me the following notice but the rest of page work fine there is no problem in the page.

```
Notice: Undefined index: action in /var/www/cafe/view/ingredients.php on line 10 Call Stack: 0.0007 333108 1. {main}() /var/www/cafe/view/ingredients.php:0
```

what should i do to remove the notice from the top of my page.

on instructions page <form method="post" action="instructions.php?action=add&id="> and on the top of this page i get the action e.g $action=$_GET['action']; but this give me the notice –

Comment: Did you like none of the answers you've gotten for your previous questions?

Comment: -1 Well, disable `error_reporting` if you are unable to triage it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP: "Notice: Undefined variable" ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to access index `action` of some array, an index that doesn't exist. Example: `$some_variable['action']`.

Try to run `var_dump($some_variable);die;` and you'll see that it doesn't exist.

Comment: on instructions page <form method="post" action="instructions.php?action=add&id=<?php echo $_GET['id'];?>"> and on the top of this page i get the action e.g $action=$_GET['action']; but this give me the notice

Comment: Please accept some answers on your other questions, to prove you won't hit n' run us again. Then I will give you further information

Comment: i accept one of the answer which worked for me from my posted question replace string in php

Comment: Then do `var_dump($_GET);die;` right before `$action=$_GET['action'];`, and provide the results, along with the URL of that page. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Read the error message and look at the line of code it refers to (line 10). You're trying to access something ('action') which isn't defined.